# Terminate / Close TLS connection when request timesout in Node using express

Tags: node.js, express, networking, mtls

I am working on a project where I have a particular requirement

1. Working on the client side of the request, I want to terminate the tls connection all together incase a request timesout (and not crash the node server)
2. Else, proceed normally with the response

I have written the following code which works fine for timeout cases (it is a hacky one though) where I am just crashing the node server whenever a timeout happens and then automatically restarting it using PM2. Pasting the snippet below.

**Requirement**
I tried to dig deeper to figure out how we can manually close a tls connection in express but was unsuccesful (hence the temporary hack). Any help from the community would be really appreciated

```
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios').default;
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express()
const port = 3000

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false, // (NOTE: this will disable client verification)
  cert: fs.readFileSync("certificate.crt"),
  key: fs.readFileSync("server.key"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync("ca.crt"),
})

const url = "--"

app.use(express.json())

app.all('/proxy', (req, res) => {

  axios.post(url, req.body, { httpsAgent, headers: req.headers, timeout: 10 * 1000 }).then((ds) => {
    res.send(ds.data)
  }).catch(() => {
    process.exit()
    res.connection.end()
  })

})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("STARTED LISTENING ON PORT: " + port.toString())
})
```